# Unique Situation - Placing text next to other text without using CSS

Tags: html

I have a very unique situation that I am going to explain as best I can!

I want to output users in a style like so:

Username:Password

Username2:Password2

etc etc...

But I cannot place text in a paragraph like `<p>Username:Password</p>`

I can only do it like so... `<p>Username:</p><p>Password</p>`

And as I can only have seperate tags on the username and password the design ents up looking like so:

Username:

Password

I also cannot use any CSS whatsoever.

But I am able to use any type of HTML tags I like! (Span tags of course wouldn't work as they would both be separate still)

Is there any possible way to do this with the rules I have given you, I have tried everything!

(I know it sounds strange what I am wanting to do but I have a strange parser software that can only do this)

Here is a snippet of the code to show you how this works:

```
$ids = Array();
$usernames = Array();
$passwords = Array();
while ($row = $getaccounts->fetch_assoc()) {
   $ids[] = $row["id"];
   $usernames[] = "<span>".$row["username"].":</span>";
   $passwords[] = "<span>".$row["password"]."</span><br />";
}
$activezero = implode(",",$ids);
$username = "".implode("",$usernames)."";
$password = "".implode("",$passwords)."";
echo $activezero;
```

I know this looks absolutely stupid, but trust me, this is the only way of getting my program to parse everything properly.

How can I make it output what I want using the code that I have?

Comment: `<span>Username:</span><span>Password</span>`

Comment: Is `dl` or `table` an option?

Comment: @Robby Cornellissen The output on my system then becomes:
email:email:passwordpassword

Answer (score 0):

There are some Options to solve this without using CSS, you could either use a table or a definition list, for example.

```html
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Username</th>
                <th>Password</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Alice:</td>
                <td>abc123</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Bob:</td>
                <td>pa$$word</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
            
    <dl>
      <dt>Alice:</dt>
      <dd>abc123</dd>
      <dt>Bob:</dt>
      <dd>pa$$word</dd>
    </dl>
```

Comment: That would work but the amount of results that I get vary from 3 results to 500 results. And I couldn't have that amount of tags due to my program.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe sth like it?

```
<span>Username:</span><span>Password</span><br />
<span>Username2:</span><span>Password2</span>
```

Username:Password
Username2:Password2

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4rtq73ks/)

Comment: Please explain your answer!

Comment: I can only output all of the usernames first and then all of the passwords after that (Or the other way round if need be.)